# How to make XStream map unmapped tags to an HashMap when parsing XML?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Have an XML document that I want to convert to a Java bean. I want to tag the missing fields in my bean to a hashMap because these field name keeps varying. Is there a way to do this?

For example, my XML looks like

```
<employee>
   <firstname>stack</firstname>
   <lastname>alpha</lastname>
   <phone1>999-999-9999</phone1>
</employee>
```

My java bean look like

```
@XstreamAlias("employee")
public class Employee {
       private String firstname;
       private String lastname;
       private map<String, String> unknownfields;
}
```

When I load the XML to my java bean, it should look like

```
firstname="stack", lastname="alpha", unknownfields=[{"phone1","999-999-9999"}]
```

Know this is a bad design, but wanted to check whether this could be implemented using xstream.

Answer (score 0):

Implement your own Converter. Take a look at [JavaBeanConverter](http://xstream/xstream/src/java/com/thoughtworks/xstream/converters/javabean/JavaBeanConverter.java) for reference implementation because you want to be as close to that a possible.

The only place you would need to handle things differently is this (within the ***unmarshal*** method)

```
if (propertyExistsInClass) {
    Class<?> type = determineType(reader, result, propertyName);
    Object value = context.convertAnother(result, type);
    beanProvider.writeProperty(result, propertyName, value);
    seenProperties.add(new FastField(resultType, propertyName));
} else {
    throw new MissingFieldException(resultType.getName(), propertyName);
}
```

Where, from the *else* block, it throws the `MissingFieldException`, you should populate your `Map`. The XML element name is easily available here, but you need to tweak for the value. The clue to get the value is in the *if* block just above:

```
Object value = context.convertAnother(result, type);
```

The only problem is you dont have a Java type to convert the value into. String maybe?

I would inherit `JavaBeanConverter` and just override the `unmarshal` method, but suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Soumik. Understood your hint. Will give it a try.